# Getting rid of Xauthority files

Tags: home-directory

I have my ~/ directory that is being flooded by ".Xauthority.43652W" files with "43652W" being any combination of letter and digits...

I only have 40 of these files for the moment, but it's ever growing and I don't want to pollute my ~/ too much.

Any idea what should I do ?

Comment: Remove them?  Just leave the base `.XAuthority` file.

Comment: :-) Nice suggestion... I would have prefer a configuration parameter that would have help me stop producing them :-)

Comment: I have just 5 since installing 13.04 in April. Before that, something similar was happening with .goutput (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those -- like me -- wishing to get rid of this "pollution" in the user directory (apparently caused by a **lightdm bug** described in [Why do I have so many .Xauthority.* files in my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299127/why-do-i-have-so-many-xauthority-files-in-my-home-directory)), **an interim solution** could be placing something like the following (executable) script file (which assumes you are the first **user** after **root**) into the `/etc/cron.daily` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="$(users | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}')"
ls /home/"$USER"/.Xauthority.* > /home/"$USER"/.Xauthority-Files.txt
NFILES="$(grep -c Xauthority /home/"$USER"/.Xauthority-Files.txt)"
LOG="/home/"$USER"/.Xauthority-Files.log"
echo -e "$(date +"%x %R"): "$NFILES" .Xauthority.* files deleted" >> "$LOG"
rm -f /home/"$USER"/.Xauthority.*
rm -f /home/"$USER"/.Xauthority-Files.txt
exit 0
```

*NOTE: This updated script keeps a log file named ".Xauthority-Files.log" so that you can follow up if a recent update has put an end to this bug, and then remove the script when it's no longer needed.*